# How to exclude opposite property values

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a Way class and have From ,To and Price properties. Question about:

```
void Main()
{
    var list=new List<Way>(){
        new Way{From="A",To="B",Price=500},
        new Way{From="A",To="C",Price=500},
        new Way{From="B",To="A",Price=500},
        new Way{From="C",To="A",Price=500}
    };
}
public class Way{
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string To { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

They are A=>B price equals B=>A how to exclude this values by opposite location?

I want result by get only A=>B location cause its same B=>A.

Comment: perhaps only allow alphabetical order, i.e. From < To ?

Comment: what should be expected output over here?

Comment: @Isparia that starts a whole "directed graph vs undirected graph" question; either can be valid

Comment: @Isparia Thanks for reply but; 
A,B,C Locations only naming they are not have relationship.

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar My expected result is have only Two data;
 1)Way{From="A",To="B",Price=500}
 2)Way{From="A",To="C",Price=500}

Comment: why not B -> A and C -> A ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a loop approach:

```
var list=new List<Way>(){
    new Way{From="A",To="B",Price=500},
    new Way{From="A",To="C",Price=500},
    new Way{From="B",To="A",Price=500},
    new Way{From="C",To="A",Price=500}
};

List<Way> resultList = new List<Way>();

foreach (var entry in list)
{
    if (resultList.Any(x => $"{x.To}{x.From}" == $"{entry.From}{entry.To}") == false)
    {
        resultList.Add(entry);
    }
}
```

thee basic idea: for each entry check whether you have already collected a counterpart in the resulting collection. If not then you can safely collect the entry.

here is an alternative if condition that does not rely on the creation of a string at each iteration:

```
if (resultList.Any(x => x.To == entry.From && x.From == entry.To) == false)
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. But may i apply this result with linq? Because im getting data from Database.

Comment: @F.BekirYücel you want to do this on the server side? not in memory ?

Comment: Is it possible? Im need this result when called query from DB with entityframework.

Comment: @F.BekirYücel that is far less trivial, because only a restricted set of linq commands can be translated to SQL commands

Comment: May i get this result with SQL query? Or which keywords maybe work?